# open source PHP shopping cart LIBRARY?

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am looking for a good PHP shopping cart LIBRARY.

My definition of GOOD means:

- well designed code (preferably documented)
- supports multiple payment gateways
- active community
- preferable POST beta version or version 1.0.0 (i.e. it is used in production systems)

I stress the word library, because most of the items turning up in my Google searches are fully fledged systems/applications - with user interfaces and templating etc.

I simply want the bare components (I only want the backend components/ NO frontend/UI parts).

Is anyone out there aware of such a PURE shopping cart LIBRARY (as described above)?

Failing that, is there an OS shopping cart 'system' out there that is designed in a loosely coupled manner, so as to make 'ripping out' the front end components relatively easy?. With all of the systems I have seen so far, the UI is tightly coupled with the backend, and it is impossible (with reasonable amount of effort), to separate between the F/E and the B/E.

So to summarize, my questions are:

1. Is anyone aware of an OS shopping cart LIBRARY (no GUI) - preferably PHP (but I can work with Python if need be)
2. If no pure LIBRARY solution exists, can someone recommend a well written (i.e. losely coupled) system that allows me to remove the UI from the 'system' (so I am left with the PURE library)?

Comment: You'd probably have an easier time tracking down payment gateway libraries, shipping calculation libraries, etc. and stitching them together into your own shopping cart code. Looking for a "shopping cart library" isn't getting you anywhere because it's not a shopping cart without a front end, so even if it existed it wouldn't be called that.

Answer (score 1):

Magento Commerce is well architected and uses an MVC pattern that would make it relatively straight forward to rip out the template/views.  The controllers do have embedded redirect logic, but the model layer is quite independent.  Definitely worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

A little late but you could take a look at the [composer packages](https://packagist.org/packages/moltin/) or the [API](http://docs.molt.in) that [Moltin](https://molt.in) offers.